# Is there an equivalent to Elasticsearch index aliases in Solr + Sunspot?

Tags: solr, indexing, alias, sunspot

With ElasticSearch, an app can point to the alias of an index, instead of the index directly, which makes it easy to switch the index the app uses.

Tire, the equivalent of Sunspot for ES, allows me to interact with aliases.

I can't find anything regarding aliases with Sunspot. How do you handle them in your apps which use Sunspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know anything about sunspot, but for Solr counts that there has been a core alias feature, until version 3.1 of Solr. This has been removed with [SOLR-1637](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1637) and has been "really, really" removed with [SOLR-6169](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6169) in version 4.9.

But with the [advent of SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud) this feature has been re-introduced with a better/different implementation [SOLR-4497](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4497) in Solr 4.2.

Unfortunately when skimming through [the Reference of Sunspost](http://outoftime.github.io/sunspot/docs/) I do not find a word about SolrCloud or aliasing. Probably that features have not been adopted by the Sunspot developers? As stated I do not know sunspot, probably they name it differently?

Most likely you will have to get your hands dirty and manage SolrCloud and in consequence aliases *not* through the API sunspot offers, but with admin interface of Solr.

Sources of information

- There is [this old Wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) that covers SolrCloud. It has a small, [separate section about creating aliases](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Collection_Aliases)
- In the official reference is also a section about [collection aliases](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api4).
- The guys of Cloudera who have donated the feature to Solr have also written [a blog post about it](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/collection-aliasing-near-real-time-search-for-really-big-data/).